# Android TextView not updating on button click

Tags: android, string, textview, android-button

I am trying to update a TextView after clicking a button. I am also appending to the String a value that is giving me from another function. For some reason, when I try to do this it doesn't update, however it works perfectly when it is just a regular String without the function.

Here is my onClick code:

```
 enterButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                MonitorObserver.updateWalk(context); 
                analyse = new WalkingAnalyse(context);
                analyse.enterActivity(Float.parseFloat(timeString), Float.parseFloat(distanceString), 0); //this is what to do whenever inserting a new activity
                recommendationTextView.setText("Recommendation: "+recommend.recommend(context)+" meters"); //it works without the recommend.recommend(context) function

        }
    });

    public String recommend(Context context){
       return Float.toString(currentRecommendation);
    }
```

I should probably also add the TextView is updated whenever I leave the screen and then return to it.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does recommend return, u might wanna add toString() at the end

Comment: @meda recommend does return a String. So the toString() would be redundant.

Comment: You get any errors? can you share the code of that recommend function?

Comment: No errors. Just nothing happens. However, if I do leave the screen and come back, it finally updates. 
I will add the recommend code to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should Set the text before entering the new activity?

```
recommendationTextView.setText("Recommendation: "+recommend.recommend(context)+" meters");
MonitorObserver.updateWalk(context); 
analyse = new WalkingAnalyse(context);
analyse.enterActivity(Float.parseFloat(timeString), Float.parseFloat(distanceString), 0);
```

Comment: Figured it out. It was actually that I forgot to create a new Recommend class.